# In Django, is it Bad to Import and use Template Tags outside a Template?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django 1.9 and Django Rest Framework.

In Django, there's a method named [timesince()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/timesince.py) and it is used in a templatetag called [humanize](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/humanize/templatetags/humanize.py), in a method called 'naturaltime'.

The natural time method returns what I want (a pretty formatted date). Timesince isn't that usable in an app.

Anyway, I'm in a serializer.py file for DRF, and I imported that method with:

```
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import naturaltime
```

Since there's an annotation **@register.filter** at the top of the method and **register = template.Library()** at the top of the templatetag file, can it cause problems when I import that not from a template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it shouldn't cause problems.

You can use the function as a regular python function. The `@register.filter` is a decorator that *decorates* the function as a `filter` while `register = template.Library()` makes it usable as a template tag.

However, it can also be called using the right signature in plain python code.

So you can do:

```
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import naturaltime
from datetime import datetime as dt

my_human_time = naturaltime(dt.now())
print(my_human_time)
# 'now'
```